# Android-Java detect when the Output-Stream has finished to write the bytes

Tags: java, android, file, file-handling

My code is working fine, I just want to show some toast when the writing the bytes are completed. I know I can add toast when I'm  done with reading the file after while loop `in.read(buf) == 0`, so the while-loop is finished. I can show toast after while, or after closing your streams. When I add toast at the end of the while loop, the files did not show exactly the same time as the toast is shown. It show itself after a few minutes. How would I know writing the bytes are completed or the `close()` tell its finished?

```
File newfile;
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File(path));
String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
File dir = new File(root + "/" + "Pictures");
if (!dir.exists()) {
    dir.mkdirs();
}
newfile = new File(dir, "status_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".mp4");
if (newfile.exists()) newfile.delete();
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(newfile);
byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
int len;
while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
    out.write(buf, 0, len);
}
in.close();
out.close();
```

Comment: Just place a Toast after close(). What is the problem?

Comment: @blackapps I don't things so its a good approach.

Comment: @blackapps did you vote down the question if you any thing unclear, you can ask.

Comment: after while loop is a good place for that

Comment: Yeah I have tried that too but its not like that while keep running and toast will show if we add it after while loop.

Comment: Please explain why you can not do it after the while loop and after you closed the streams. You are done, reading the file, at this point.

Comment: hmmm. is this code runs in another thread (not main)?

Comment: It is pretty unclear which problem you encounter. All makes no sense.

Comment: @ChristianB are their any listeners for this like Oncomplete?

Comment: @blackapps all I want to know when the writing the bytes are completed.

Comment: @ChristianB your saying just add the toast at the end of code?

Comment: you are done with reading the file after your while loop `in.read(buf) == 0`, so the while-loop is finshed. Show your toast after while, or after closing your streams. There is nothing else to explain here.

Comment: @ChristianB I got your point, but the files did not show exactly the same time as the toast is shown. It show its self after few mint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Their is no way to track down the **OutputStream** has finished to write the bytes, just you can add toast or something after `close()`.